# Visualize sound pitch and rhythm in Python

Tags: python, signal-processing, audio-processing

Is there any python library to visualize the pitch and rhythm of the sound. Like  this [paper's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.11284.pdf) Figure 3? I read this [doc](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/master/_modules/librosa/core/pitch.html) but it doesn't seem the thing I want.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish that, you have three tasks:

- record the sound in a digitized form (example: WAV file)
- compute the components of the sound
- plot a graph

Natural sounds from animals and persons aren't pure, our vocalizations are the result of overlapping pitches.

With an artificial instrument (computer, synthetizer, etc...) you can generate sounds with only one pitch.

---

This is an example of a possible solution.
To load a sound sample from file, you can use the library Pygame:
https://www.pygame.org/news

To find the  components of the sound sample, the most common solution is the Fourier transform.
On computers the algorithms are called DFT and FFT:
https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html

To plot the results, you can use Pygame.

---

This article is a very good introduction to audio and digital signal processing in python:
https://www.pythonforengineers.com/audio-and-digital-signal-processingdsp-in-python/

It illustrates the analysis of a sound, building python code step by step with a lot of explanations and images. 
I strongly suggest you to read it.